# Loading delayed_jobs from lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a file in `lib/jobs` with definitions of a bunch of jobs. I've added `lib` to autoload path and can create these jobs in Rails console just fine. But delayed_job worker doesn't see them and produces an error `Jobs::Vk::PhotoJob failed with NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for Jobs::Vk:Module`. Job definition file looks something like this:

```
module Jobs
  module Vk
    class PhotoJob
    end
  end
end
```

How can I make these classes visible to delayed_job worker?